# Cast Exception in Jasper Reports "Could not create the report java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer"

Tags: java, swing, casting, jasper-reports

I am new to jasper reports. I have created one report with SQL Server Stored Procedure.When viewing the report from Swing frame i am getting the following exception.

```
 Could not create the report java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

I have defined the report's parameters with the same data type as of the stored procedure's definition in sql Server 2000.

Following is the part of the .jrxml file showing the parameter and query of the stored proc call.

```
  <parameter name="CatID" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="Start" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<parameter name="Stop" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<parameter name="GoldID" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="Percentage" class="java.lang.Float"/>
<parameter name="Karat" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<parameter name="DiaGrade" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<parameter name="StoneGrade" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[{call PriceList($P{CatID},$P{Start}  ,$P{Stop},$P{GoldID},$P{Karat},$P{StoneGrade} ,$P{DiaGrade},$P{Percentage} ) }]]>
</queryString>
<field name="Design" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="DesignP" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="Model" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="GoldCode" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="CatID" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="OrnID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="StoneID" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="ProfitPer" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<field name="PlatingChg" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="SetCode" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="CompCost" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<field name="USRate" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<field name="CCost" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<field name="Karat" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="GoldIDConv" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="StoneGrade" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="DiaGrade" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="CompCost1" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<field name="GCost" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<field name="ACost" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<field name="SCost" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<field name="Cost" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<field name="Percentage" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
<field name="Price" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
```

Part of my Stored proc is as following

```
    create PROCEDURE PriceList
@CatID      char(1),
@Start      int,
@Stop       int,
@GoldID     char(1),
@Karat      tinyInt,
@StoneGrade tinyint,
@DiaGrade   tinyInt,
@Percentage numeric(6,3)

    AS
    DECLARE @mGold varchar(4),
         @TotStones int,
     @StoneGradePrice int,
     @CurrRate numeric(9,5)


Select @mGold = ''

Select @CurrRate = Rate From Currency Where Currency = 1
           Select @TotStones = 0


Select @StoneGradePrice = 0

    IF @GoldID='W'
SELECT @mGold='W'


    IF @GoldID='N'
    SELECT @mGold='WN'


   IF @GoldID='P'
   SELECT @mGold='PT'

  IF @GoldID = 'Z' 
  Select @mGold = '(2T)'
  IF @GoldID = 'Q' 
  Select @mGold = '(2P)'
  SELECT    Design=convert(varchar(20),Design+@mGold),
  DesignP=Design,Model=dbo.GetModel(Design),GoldCode=@mGold,
    CatID,
    OrnID,
    StoneID,
    ProfitPer,
    PlatingChg,
    SetCode,
            CompCost ,
    USRate=@CurrRate,
    CCost=CUS/@CurrRate
INTO #CTemp
FROM Charges a
WHERE a.CatID=@CatID
     AND OrnID BETWEEN @Start AND @Stop



   IF @GoldID='0'or @GoldID = 'Z'  or @GoldID = 'T' or @GoldID = 'Q'   or @GoldID = 'V' 
SELECT  a.CatID,
OrnID,Small=max(isnull(b.Small,0)), Medium=max(isnull(b.Medium,0)), Large=max(isnull(b.Large,0)),Karat=@Karat,GCost=SUM(GUS),KChainConv=max(KChainConv)
INTO #GTemp
FROM GoldCost a left outer  join CatGoldPlatingChg b on a.catid = b.catid  and b.GoldID = @GoldID
WHERE a.CatID=@CatID AND mKarat=@Karat
     AND OrnID BETWEEN @Start AND @Stop 
GROUP BY a.CatID,OrnID

    SELECT  a.*,
    b.Karat,
    GoldIDConv=@GoldID,
StoneGrade,
    DiaGrade,
        CompCost1=coalesce(CompCost *((100+KChainConv)/100),0),
    GCost=coalesce(GCost,0) +( coalesce((case PlatingChg when 1 then           Small        when 2 then Medium else Large end),0)/@CurrRate) ,
                       ACost=coalesce(ACost,0),
    SCost= coalesce(SCost,0),
    Cost=coalesce(CCost,0)+ coalesce(ACost,0) + coalesce(GCost,0)+ (coalesce((case PlatingChg when 1 then Small when 2 then Medium else Large end),0)/@CurrRate) +coalesce(SCost,0) + coalesce(CompCost *((100+KChainConv)/100),0),
    Percentage=@Percentage,
    Price=(convert(numeric(10,0),ceiling((((
           coalesce(CCost,0)+ coalesce(ACost,0) + coalesce(GCost,0) + (coalesce((case PlatingChg when 1 then Small when 2 then Medium else Large end),0)/@CurrRate) +coalesce(SCost,0)) * (100+ProfitPer))/100) + coalesce((CompCost) *((100+KChainConv)/100),0) )  * (100+@Percentage)/100))
FROM #CTemp a
    LEFT JOIN tempdb.#GTemp b ON (a.CatID=b.CatID AND a.OrnID=b.OrnID )
    LEFT JOIN tempdb.#ATemp d ON (a.CatID=d.CatID AND a.OrnID=d.OrnID )
    LEFT JOIN tempdb.#STemp c ON (a.CatID=c.CatID AND a.OrnID=c.OrnID  AND a.StoneID=c.StoneID)
WHERE b.GCOST IS NOT NULL AND c.SCOST IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY a.CatID,a.OrnID
```

Comment: `..<field name="OrnID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="StoneID" class="java.lang.String"/>..`  Why is `StoneID` a `String`?

Comment: *"Defined in Database"*  Can you say that in fewer words, and vague it up for me?  Are you for example saying that the Orn ID is defined in the DB as an `Integer`, while the Stone ID is (for some odd reason) defined in the DB as a `String`?  What is the typical form of the `StoneID` values?

Comment: @Prog_Anila Could you post the snippet of your stored procedure?

Comment: @Prog_Anila Could you post the snippet of code that executes the report, and possibly the full stacktrace?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson the sample Stone ID's are Y,S,T etc

Comment: @Alex K i just posted part of my stored proc.

Comment: @jschoen  Actually it is not the exception but it is the error message displayed by the Report engine as when i catched the exception and print e.printStackTrace(); nothing happened.

Answer (score -1):

The error is very clear:

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

You are trying to cast a String object to an Integer. That cannot be done. They are not of the same type. So verify input data and defined fields data types accordingly. One of them is the cause of exception.

Comment: @Shehzad  I am not doing any casting simply i created a simple jasper report (.jrxml) file with IReports and specified the parameter list with same data type as of the stored proc's parameter list when i specified <queryString>
    <![CDATA[{call PriceList($P{CatID},$P{Start}  ,$P{Stop},$P{GoldID},$P{Karat},$P{StoneGrade} ,$P{DiaGrade},$P{Percentage} ) }]]>
</queryString>
the report automatically gets the  fields of the stored proc's result set.